# how to convert unicode to printable string in QT stream

Tags: qt, encoding, character-encoding

I'm writing a stream to a file and stdout, but I'm getting some kind of encoding like this:

> \u05ea\u05e7\u05dc\u05d9\u05d8
>   \u05e9\u05e1\u05d9\u05de\u05dc
>   \u05e9\u05d9\u05e0\u05d5\u05d9
>   \u05d1\u05e1\u05d2\u05e0\u05d5\u05df
>   \u05dc\u05d3\u05e2\u05ea\u05d9
>   \u05d0\u05dd \u05d0\u05e0\u05d9
>   \u05d6\u05d5\u05db\u05e8
>   \u05e0\u05db\u05d5\u05df

How can I convert this to a printable string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't figure out how you are printing the string, but that is just Unicode:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  QString s = "\u05ea\u05e7\u05dc\u05d9\u05d8 \u05e9\u05e1\u05d9\u05de\u05dc \u05e9\u05d9\u05e0\u05d5\u05d9 \u05d1\u05e1\u05d2\u05e0\u05d5\u05df \u05dc\u05d3\u05e2\u05ea\u05d9 \u05d0\u05dd \u05d0\u05e0\u05d9 \u05d6\u05d5\u05db\u05e8 \u05e0\u05db\u05d5\u05df";

  QFile file1("1.txt");
  if (!file1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return 1;

  QTextStream out(&file1);
  out << s << "\n";

  qDebug() << s;
  return 0;
}
```

If I compile and run it

```
g++ -lQtCore -I /usr/include/QtCore test.cpp 
./a.out
```

I can see the printable characters both in the console debug output and in the file:

```
"תקליט שסימל שינוי בסגנון לדעתי אם אני זוכר נכון"
```

So you are probably doing something wrong or looking in the wrong direction, can you paste your code so we can help you better?

Comment: That's not UTF-8.  `\uXXXX` is a *Unicode escape sequence*: a textual representation of a Unicode code point.

Comment: Thanks, You are right. Those are Unicode based characters. AFAIK there is no UTF-8 escape sequences because UTF-8 is just a way to write/encode Unicode equivalent characters.

The resulting file is encoded in UTF-8:

$ file 1.txt 
1.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text